# Workaround for bug in Oblivion "Scheduled for Execution" quest?

Tags: ps3, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

After completing the "[Scheduled for Execution](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Scheduled_for_Execution)" quest in Oblivion, the game always tells me that a guard died and I have lost the bonus for that contract. The problem is, all the guards are alive, even after that message is displayed. Does anyone know what causes this, and if there is a workaround?

I suspect that this is a bug caused by killing Captain Gepard Montrose earlier, before starting this quest. During the quest, he is alive again, and I'm guessing that the game is remembering that he was killed previously even though the quest has revived him.

Answer (score 4):

Most Oblivon bug workarounds are sadly unavailable on the console versions, as they require use of the developer console.

Comment: Also, that's a bit ironic.